# Primary Key Issues with ManyToManyField Relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am attempting to use ManyToMany relationships in Django and almost everything is working perfectly.  I have **resources** and **case studies**.  The objective is to have (case studies) able to pull any number of items from the resources table.

Here is what works perfectly

- I can add resources
- I can edit resources
- I can add case studies
- I can edit case studies

I cannot

- I cannot delete resources
- I cannot delete case studies

I have one relational table to handle this relationship:

**casestudy_resource** (table)

```
   casestudy_id      resource_id
   1                 2
   1                 5
   1                 9
```

**Models.py**

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=False, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=pdf_location, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Casestudy(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=False, blank=False)
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_location, null=True, blank=True, help_text="120w x 100h")
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=pdf_location, null=True, blank=True)
    resource = models.ManyToManyField(Resource, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Case Study"
        verbose_name_plural = "Case Studies"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**PRIMARY KEY ISSUE**

I receive the following database exception when performing a delete from the above code:

```
no such column: casestudy_resource.id
```

---

**SECONDARY ISSUE**

When adding a primary key to fix the above column, only null values appear in the primary key column.  They are oddly not auto-generated like all other primary keys in Django models:

**casestudy_resource** (table)

```
    id        casestudy_id      resource_id
    NULL      1                 2
    NULL      1                 5
    NULL      1                 9
```

This then causes the following exception when dealing with deleting of resources or case studies:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resource'
```

Comment: You could delete the case study resources manually first. If you are happy to delete all the case studies resources automatically; all you need is to add "on_delete=models.CASCADE" to your foreign key. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: What are you trying to delete and how?

Comment: François - I tried this already.  I used the ManyToManyField attribute called, "through" which linked directly to a new class that had two ForeignKey references.  One ForeignKey for the resource_id, and one for the casestudy_id.  This caused the ManyToManyField field to not appear at all in the administration panel.

Comment: AKS - I'm just attempting to delete either a case study or general resource asset from within the Django administrator.

Comment: The working solution (which is admittedly quite hacky): since only delete operations are being affected, I have a show/hide flag with filter views to show desired assets only.  Would still love to know the proper solution, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your new `id` column using something like this (Postgres only):

```
UPDATE casestudy_resource SET id = nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('casestudy_resource','id'));
```

The column needs to be added as both, `SERIAL` and `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
ALTER TABLE casestudy_resource ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;
UPDATE casestudy_resource SET id = nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('casestudy_resource','id'));
ALTER TABLE casestudy_resource ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a project that I inherited and uses SQLite 3 (so the above won't work).  This project will only be running for another couple months before being replaced, too.  So for the time, I'm doing a show/hide flag with updated filter views to show desired assets, which is admittedly quite hacky.  However, I perused a ton of stackoverflow questions, Django documentation and have yet to find a good answer to this and wanted something up for everyone who's in my shoes.

Comment: Using sqlite, AFAIK the only way to add a primary key is: create a new table, copy the data to the new table, drop old table, rename new table.